How to Dynamically create a Nullable<T>
I need to dynamically create an instance from a specific type T.  For some reason I am having trouble getting this to work for Nullable<> types.
For context, this code works fine, assuming T is Guid?
var instance = new Nullable<Guid>();
var hasValue = instance.HasValue; // returns false

This dynamic code, however, crashes on the call to HasValue, due to a null reference.
var type = typeof(T);
var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
var nullableType = typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(underlyingType);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(nullableType);
var hasValue = instance.HasValue; // crashes because instance is null

How can I create a Nullable instance that is equivalent to creating one when the type is unknown?

What is T? Because Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(Guid)) throws an exception. If T is Guid?, it works fine.

yeah T is Guid?  I mixed up some code samples. fixed now

@gunr2171 yes your example works fine because T is hardcoded to Guid?.  I can't get the same to work dynamically

What about this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/2phdlw

@gunr2171 thanks for putting that together - it's not working on my local machine, but it looks like my code is correct, then?   perhaps something else is at play.  Appreciate the support.

@JosephGabriel Activator.CreateInstance method returns an object. How do you access the HasValue property of an object? That would result into a compile-time error, "Object does not contain definition of HasValue...."

If you type T is constrained to be a struct, you can do Nullable<T> instance = default;.  Or just T? instance = default;

Don't try to do raw generics with reflection. Write a generic method to do the generics, then use reflection to call it.


I need to dynamically create an instance from a specific type T. For some reason I am having trouble getting this to work for Nullable<> types.

Are you aware that the Nullable<T> type has special boxing and unboxing behavior?

If you box a Nullable<T> instance that doesn’t have a value, then the result is null.
Conversely, if you unbox null to any Nullable<T> type, then the result is a Nullable<T> instance that doesn’t have a value.
If you box a Nullable<T> instance that has a value, then the result is a box of type T that contains the value. (The result is not a box of type Nullable<T>.)

Therefore, when you execute
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(nullableType);

to create a default Nullable<T> instance (one that doesn’t have a value), Activator.CreateInstance will always return null.

This dynamic code, however, crashes on the call to HasValue, due to a null reference.
var hasValue = instance.HasValue; // crashes because instance is null


This code doesn’t compile because the type of instance is object, and object doesn’t have a HasValue property. Please update your question with code that compiles and reproduces the problem you’re asking about.

How can I create a Nullable instance that is equivalent to creating one when the type is unknown?

The dynamic equivalent of new Nullable<T>() is what you already have: Activator.CreateInstance(nullableType). Casting null to Nullable<T> will yield a Nullable<T> instance whose HasValue property returns false.

re: "Conversely, if you unbox null to any Nullable type, then the result is a Nullable instance that doesn’t have a value."  - this is what I was missing.

If your code already has a generic T, per your example, this should work to create a Nullable<T>:
T? CreateNullable<T>() where T : struct
{
    return null;
}



How can I create a Nullable instance that is equivalent to creating one when the type is unknown?

Firstly, you need recognize the type of T, since there is Value/Reference type in C#, and Reference type could not create Nullable since it is already nullable.
Check if Value Type by
typeof(Guid).IsValueType

Switch case if is Value Type, and invoke method accrodingly
static Nullable<T> CreateValueType<T>() where T : struct
{
    return new Nullable<T>();
}

static T? CreateReferenceType<T>() where T : class
{
    T? t = null;

    return t;
}

Note:
Value Type: Basic type, struct and enum are value types
Reference Type: Class, Interface, delegate, event etc.
Test(Here you need identify Type to create instance according to your unknow Type):
var nullGuid = CreateValueType<Guid>();
var nullEnum = CreateValueType<MyType>();
var nullValue = CreateValueType<int>();
var nullClass = CreateReferenceType<MyClass>();

enum MyType : int
{
    None = 0,
}

class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}


I haven't tested this, but I think the issue is that Activator.CreateInstance method returns an object, and an object doesn't have a HasValue property, so you would get a compile-time error.
You have to use reflection to get the value of the HasValue property:
var type = typeof(T);
var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
var nullableType = typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(underlyingType);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(nullableType);

// Use reflection to get the value of the HasValue property
var property = typeof(Nullable<>).GetProperty("HasValue");
var hasValue = (bool)property.GetValue(instance);



instance  can never be of type Nullable<T>  because nullables aren't boxed. instance is either going to be null or a boxed T.

@EtiennedeMartel can you please clarify what you are trying to say? Also, I don't understand the reason for downvoting my answer whoever did that, it would be nice to explain why

I downvoted it because it's wrong. See Michael Liu's answer for the detailed explanation, but in short: your code can never work.

@EtiennedeMartel I'm sure many developers don't know the nuances of boxing and unboxing related to Nullable that Michael Lui explained in their answer, so again don't think downvoting is necessary in this case. I for one, never needed to know that in my 10 years as a developer. In fact if you read my answer, you will notice that I said something similar to what Michael said in their answer, " I think the issue is that Activator.CreateInstance method returns an object, and an object doesn't have a HasValue property".

It returns null. It will always return null. Just because you don't know that doesn't mean you can ignore that fact. I will downvote an answer if it contains something that's untrue, even if it's something a lot of people believe.
